# How do I turn list values into an array with an index that matches the other dic values?

Tags: python

Hoping someone can help me out. I've spent the past couple hours trying to solve this, and fair warning, I'm still fairly new to python.

This is a repost of a question I recently deleted. I've misinterpreted my code in the last example.The correct example is:

I have a dictionary, with a list that looks similar to:

```
dic = [
  {
    'name': 'john',
    'items': ['pants_1', 'shirt_2','socks_3']
  },
  {
    'name': 'bob',
    items: ['jacket_1', 'hat_1']
  }
]
```

I'm using `.append` for both `'name'`, and `'items'`, which adds the `dic` values into two new lists:

```
for x in dic:
    dic_name.append(dic['name'])
    dic_items.append(dic['items'])
```

I need to split the item value using `'_'` as the delimiter, so I've also split the values by doing:

```
name, items = [i if i is None else i.split('_')[0] for i in dic_name],
              [if i is None else i.split('_')[0] for i in chain(*dic_items)])
```

`None` is used in case there is no value. This provides me with a new list for `name, items`, with the delimiter used. Disregard the fact that I used '_' split for names in this example.

When I use this, the index for `name`, and `item` no longer match. Do i need to create the listed items in an array to match the `name` index, and if so, how?

Ideally, I want `name[0]` (which is john), to also match `items[0]` (as an array of the items in the list, so pants, shirt, socks). This way when I refer to index `0` for `name`, it also grabs all the values for `items` as index `0`. The same thing regarding the index used for bob `[1]`, which should match his items with the same index.

@avinash-raj, thanks for your patience, as I've had to update my question to reflect more closely to the code I'm working with.

Comment: There are duplicate keys in your dictionary.

Comment: Some advices: please put your code in one piece (useful for those who may copy-paste it) and cut your lines of code after 80 characters.

Comment: Can you share the expected output... and should you comprehension be on dic_items not dic_name?

Comment: @Malik, thanks, i meant to separate each dic, so it's a list of dict keys, but one doc key (items) is also considered a list. [updated. eric, will keep that in mind next time.

Comment: @achampion, my current output is 'name >> ['joe','bob']' and 'items >> ['pants','shirt','socks' jacket','hat']', which breaks the index matching the original values, ideally i'd like 'name >> ['joe','bob']' and 'items >> ['pants,shirt,socks']['jacket','hat']' which then provides a correct match.

Comment: The second `items` key should probably be a string, too. And it's confusing to call a list `dic`. Better use a plural term like `dicts`.

Comment: What do you want to do with the number you split off shirt_2?

Comment: @achampion, in reality, the items signify the hostname, and the number signifies the port. so comparing to my code, it would be similar to poobox_80

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm reading a little bit between the lines but are you trying to just collapse the list and get rid of the field names, e.g.:

```
>>> dic = [{'name': 'john', 'items':['pants_1','shirt_2','socks_3']},
           {'name': 'bob', 'items':['jacket_1','hat_1']}]
>>> data = {d['name']: dict(i.split('_') for i in d['items']) for d in dic}
>>> data
{'bob': {'hat': '1', 'jacket': '1'},
 'john': {'pants': '1', 'shirt': '2', 'socks': '3'}}
```

Now the data is directly related vs. indirectly related via a common index into 2 lists. If you want the dictionary split out you can always

```
>>> dic_name, dic_items = zip(*data.items())
>>> dic_name
('bob', 'john')
>>> dic_items
({'hat': '1', 'jacket': '1'}, {'pants': '1', 'shirt': '2', 'socks': '3'})
```

Comment: That is correct, I am collapsing the keys as I am only interested in the values, and that they match the original key/index.

Answer (score 2):

You **need** a *list* of dictionaries because the duplicate keys `name` and `items` are overwritten:

```
items = [[i.split('_')[0] for i in d['items']] for d in your_list]
names = [d['name'] for d in your_list] # then grab names from list
```

Alternatively, you can do this in one line with the built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) method and generators, like so:

```
names, items = zip(*((i['name'], [j.split('_')[0] for j in i['items']]) for i in dic))
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Looping Techniques](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) in the Tutorial.

```
for name, items in div.items():
    names.append(name)
    items.append(item)
```

That will work if your dict is structured

```
{'name':[item1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the loop body of

```
for x in dic:
    dic_name.append(dic['name'])
    dic_items.append(dic['items'])
```

you'll probably want to access `x` (to which the items in `dic` will be assigned in turn) rather than `dic`.

Comment: Each item needs to be parsed.

Comment: What do you mean, @MalikBrahimi ? My answer just points out one probable mistake in the code posted in the question. It might well be that it isn't the only mistake in that code.

Comment: He wants the first element in the each item after it is split at the underscore.